# axis range in scatter graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, limit, scatter

I have been using the code below to plot the time spent to run 4 functions. The x axis represents the number of executions whereas the y axis represents the time spent 
running a function.

I was wondering if you could help me accomplish the following:

1) set the limits of the x axis so that only positive values are shown (x represents
the number of times each function was executed and is, therefore, always positive)

2) create a legend for the 4 functions

Thank you,

Mark

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab


r = mlab.csv2rec('performance.csv')

fig = Figure(figsize=(9,6))

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_title("Function performance",fontsize=14)

ax.set_xlabel("code executions",fontsize=12)

ax.set_ylabel("time(s)",fontsize=12)

ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')

ax.scatter(r.run,r.function1,s=10,color='tomato');
ax.scatter(r.run,r.function2,s=10,color='violet');
ax.scatter(r.run,r.function3,s=10,color='blue');
ax.scatter(r.run,r.function4,s=10,color='green');

canvas.print_figure('performance.png',dpi=700)
```

Comment: What problem are you having when you try to do it yourself? Do you not know how to set the axis limits or to create a legend? (both questions are easily answered by searching the documentation) Have you tried it and gotten an error message?

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for your message. I have been trying to set the x axis limit by using ax.xlim([0,150]) but that results in the following error message: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlim'. I am not sure if using scatter() would give me flexibility to work on the axes limits.

Comment: As for legend, I used this: ax.scatter(r.run,r.time,s=10,color='tomato', marker='o',label='function1') but nothing appeared in the png file.

Comment: @Mark - You want `ax.set_xlim(..)`, rather than `ax.xlim`. Also, you don't need scatter for what you're doing in this particular case. `plot` would make more sense. Scatter is intended to vary marker colors and/or sizes by a 3rd and/or 4th variable.  In your case, `ax.plot(r.run, r.function1, 'o', color='whatever')` would make more sense.

Comment: You should thank him by marking his answer correct.   ;)

Answer (score 25):

You need to call [`legend`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html) for the legend to appear. The `label` kwarg only sets the `_label` attribute on the artist object in question. It's there for convenience, so that the label in the legend can be clearly associated with the plotting command. It won't add the legend to the plot without explicitly calling `ax.legend(...)`.  Also, you want `ax.set_xlim`, not `ax.xlim` to adjust the xaxis limits. Have a look at [`ax.axis`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis) as well.

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 22, 2)
f1, f2, f3, f4 = np.cumsum(np.random.random((4, x.size)) - 0.5, axis=1)

# It's much more convenient to just use pyplot's factory functions...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title("Function performance",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("code executions",fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("time(s)",fontsize=12)
ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')

colors = ['tomato', 'violet', 'blue', 'green']
labels = ['Thing One', 'Thing Two', 'Thing Three', 'Thing Four']
for func, color, label in zip([f1, f2, f3, f4], colors, labels):
    ax.plot(x, func, 'o', color=color, markersize=10, label=label)

ax.legend(numpoints=1, loc='upper left')
ax.set_xlim([0, x.max() + 1])

fig.savefig('performance.png', dpi=100)
```

[image]