# Python: Reading CSV file and plotting a scatter

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scatter

I've written a script to compute large csv files in dimensions: 27000 rows x 22 column. 
How can I read in the CSV file in order to use it in matplotlib in a scattered plot like the one in this thread?

[axis range in scatter graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376330/axis-range-in-scatter-graphs)

The concept of generating a scatter plot is understood. Attempts have been made to parse csv file by e.g.:

```
data=csv.reader(open('some_file.csv, 'rb'), delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
```

but without success.

Comment: What -- specifically -- does "but without success" mean?  Can you provide error messages or other indications of what's wrong?  We can't really guess.

Comment: We do need more information, but there's also a syntax error in your code as posted here: `'somefile.csv` needs a closing single quote.  Was that just a typo?

Comment: @Mike: Without an **actual** error message, that could very well the problem.  Or.  The problem could be that data is only a reader, not the actual data that's desired.

Comment: apologies for the late response. I did two massive faults: 1st-I've selected the wrong delimiter, the 2nd mistake was marcus and dm pointed to it: I've not had in mind that data is a file-like object...and probably a 3rd mistake: I haven't been any precise about the problems I had *blush*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a quick solution

```
def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter="\t")
    return [result[column] for result in results]
```

and then you can use it like this

```
time = getColumn("filename",0)
volt = getColumn("filaname",1)

plt.figure("Time/Volt")
plt.xlabel("Time(ms)")
plt.ylabel("Volt(mV)")
plt.plot(time,volt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that the correct delimiter? Did you read the documentation?  http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

`data` is a file-like object.  you  must iterate over it to access the data.  each line is a list as marcus points out in his example.